w -s command segmentation fault in 24.04.1
My question is - how to solve this or report it somewhere?
I updated to 24.04.1 on a couple of machines. I have a script start failing and it turns out it runs w command (Show who is logged on and what they are doing).
It seems now on 24.04.1 running w with -s or --short (Use the short format.  Don't print the login time, JCPU or PCPU times.) always causes a segmentation fault. Just running w works fine.
SegFault happens on both 20.04.1 upgraded machines, but not on a couple of others on lower versions.
Kernel 6.8.0-41-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug  2 20:41:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu shows a nice window with all the crash information but stupidly you can't seem to select/copy/paste anything from it! Not sure what is relevant vs irrelevant but a bit of info:
w from procps-ng 4.0.4
w crashed with SIGSEGV in __libc_start_call_main()
SegvReason: reading NULL VMA


Start with this. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

@DavidDE o.k. thanks, looking there I see it's already reported/confirmed in Debian procps package: https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/procps/+bug/2067250

This looks like a known issue w -sf and w -si segfault when systemd support is enabled and should be fixed in future releases by ps: Don't crash when using short option

ls -larth /var/crash/
